# Octopus Deploy deploys non-transformed config files

Tags: deployment, octopus-deploy, web.config-transform

I am currently configuring Octopus Deploy for our team's applications. It's fair straightforward and quite intuitive to set up.

During deployment it correctly performs `*.config` file transformation. `Web.config` is processed to use data in `Web.Test.config` and `Web.Release.config` as expected during those deployments. However, the other config file remains deployed - on a Test deployment I get `Web.Release.config` pushed to the Tentacle.

I could write a simple script step in my deployment to remove them, but I was wondering if anyone knows a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octopus deploy by default would only do transformations of files which are directly in the package and deployed to a target environment machines.
It does not automatically remove the transforms and you could achieve this via [postDeploy.ps1](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+scripts#Customscripts-ScriptsinPackages) or use the [File System - Clean Configuration Transforms](http://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-file-system-clean-configuration-transforms) template.

[image: Default transform feature]

Comment: Thanks. The transform works fine, I just don't want our other configuration config files being deployed (i.e. the `Web.Release.config` residing on the test server). I figured it would be a post-deploy script.

Comment: In octopus library there is a [File System - Clean Configuration Transforms](https://library.octopus.com/step-templates/9a2b84db-2940-4d9a-b61f-c82df35cee6c/actiontemplate-file-system-clean-configuration-transforms) template. Use it to remove transformation files from deploy environment.

Answer (score -1):

When we deploy we use the output of a production build. In that output there is only one web.config (msbuild has allready done the transformation). Then, when we deploy to test (or any other environment besides production) we manually do the transformation using https://ctt.codeplex.com/. I think this gives you the best package (less files) and you deploy optimized, production code to all of your environments.